# How to target just the second line of a paragraph

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to make the second line of a continues paragraph to align with where the paragraph first starts.

I have attached an image below of my currently look as well as my code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkVUP.png)

```css
.headline h1, .headline p {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 16px;  
}
.headline h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.headline {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

/* ======================= miss baker qoute settings ======================= */
.qoutebaker {
    margin-left: 85px;
    color: #c7c7c7;
}

/* ======================= heading 1 ======================= */
h1, h2{
    font-size: 6em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.6;
    letter-spacing: 1.4px;
    margin: 50px 0 0 85px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#cfb98b, #a27e4d);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

}
```

```html
    <div class="headline">
        <h1 class="qoutebaker">Miss Baker:</h1>
        <p>“Do they miss me?” she cried ecstatically.“Do they miss me?” she cried ecstatically.“Do they miss me?” she cried ecstatically.“Do they miss me?” she cried ecstatically.“Do they miss me?” she cried ecstatically.“Do they miss me?” she cried ecstatically.“Do they miss me?” she cried ecstatically.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have no issue using javascript to archive this, where would be my best starting point?

Comment: Make `p` and `h1` display:block then set their parent `headline` display:flex

Comment: Indeed...if you aren't wedded to your current CSS - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/GRRVeQR

Answer (score 0):

use flexbox for this.  Add margin to p tag if you want to lower the text

```css
.headline h1, .headline p {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 16px;  
}
.headline h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.headline {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

/* ======================= miss baker qoute settings ======================= */
.qoutebaker {
    margin-left: 85px;
    color: #c7c7c7;
}

/* ======================= heading 1 ======================= */
h1, h2{
    font-size: 6em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.6;
    letter-spacing: 1.4px;
    margin: 0px 0 0 85px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#cfb98b, #a27e4d);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

}

.headline{
display:flex;
align-items:center;

margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline">
        <h1 class="qoutebaker">Miss Baker:</h1>
        <p>“Do they miss me?” she cried ecstatically.“Do they miss me?” she cried ecstatically.“Do they miss me?” she cried ecstatically.“Do they miss me?” she cried ecstatically.“Do they miss me?” she cried ecstatically.“Do they miss me?” she cried ecstatically.“Do they miss me?” she cried ecstatically.</p>
    </div>
```